# Class Templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates

How should this template based class declaration be read?

I understand that a class can inherit from another class that's based on a template, but here it seems the class `MyClass` is directly inheriting from the template type B.

```
 template <typename A, typename B>
     
     class MyClass final : public B {
        using XX = B;
    
        /*
            Rest of the class definition
        */
      }
```

Comment: yes, `MyClass<A,B>` inherits from `B`. You already answered your question. What is confusing you?

Comment: Do you have any problems with that code (besides the missing `;` after the class definition)? I can't spot a question in your question.

Comment: `B` could very well be a template class. This definition doesn't preclude that.

Comment: "...s directly inheriting from the template type B." do you mean "... from the template parameter B" ? or do you mean `B` itself is a template?

Comment: @idclev463035818 . That's what I'm wondering. The above MyClass declaration feels a bit circuitous (C++ noob alert) with B being a typename, which is also being inherited from. Where's the definition of B?

Comment: @eternal_learner It comes from the instantiation of the template. `MyClass<int, MyOtherClass>` would inherit from `MyOtherClass`.

Comment: When you've wrapped your head around this, you can progress to the truly mind-bending: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @JerryCoffin. I'll certainly give reading that a shot.